# web application take information from my pc

Tags: java, python, web, project

I have project and It's the first time I work on web app .

my project have two part one on my pc and one page on web server .

I have to connect from web page to my pc to get information .

what is language should I learn for this project.

my experiences

C++,java,python

my platform 
Linux

Comment: What kind of information? Maybe Active-X and C#? There are a bunch of languages that could suit your needs.

Comment: I want secure communication like ssh and who enter the page must have user and password  . It's connect to  Sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of C++, Java and Python will do for communication between your computer and a server. Beyond that, these "best language" questions are usually unanswerable. Any language should be capable of doing the task. It's only at the level of very specific requirements that you might be able to give an argument that one language is better for the task. On top of that, different people prefer different languages, and there's little point in arguing about their personal taste.

In short, use what you like.

For building the web page, of course, you will probably need to know some HTML, CSS and possibly javascript.

Comment: if you only require very basic information about the client (your PC) like IP-Address you can completely rely on web-languages (php/javascript/ajax). Having an mix of websites and some client-side software sending data to the server is ugly to code/maintain... (smells like some nasty plugin for MS IE)

Comment: Probably, but not necessarily, and I'll give the guy the benefit of the doubt.